# Kill a running subprocess call

Tags: python, multithreading, subprocess

I'm launching a program with `subprocess` on Python.

In some cases the program may freeze. This is out of my control. The only thing I can do from the command line it is launched from is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> which kills the program quickly.

Is there any way to emulate this with `subprocess`? I am using `subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)` to launch the program.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
p = subprocess.Popen("echo 'foo' && sleep 60 && echo 'bar'", shell=True)
p.kill()
```

Check out the docs on the `subprocess` module for more info: http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Comment: Should probably try to terminate before outright killing it.

Comment: Tried terminate and then kill, subprocess still runs!!

Comment: that's probably because of shell=True

Comment: Note that unless you wait() on the process after killing it, you'll create zombie processes, `ResourceWarning: subprocess 512574 is still running`  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55052055/why-do-i-get-subprocess-resource-warnings-despite-the-process-being-dead

Answer (score 25):

Well, there are a couple of methods on the object returned by `subprocess.Popen()` which may be of use: [`Popen.terminate()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.terminate) and [`Popen.kill()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.kill), which send a `SIGTERM` and `SIGKILL` respectively.

For example...

```
import subprocess
import time

process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)
time.sleep(5)
process.terminate()
```

...would terminate the process after five seconds.

Or you can use [`os.kill()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.kill) to send other signals, like `SIGINT` to simulate CTRL-C, with...

```
import subprocess
import time
import os
import signal

process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)
time.sleep(5)
os.kill(process.pid, signal.SIGINT)
```

Comment: On Windows `kill = terminate` and signals do not work the same way.

Comment: This answer is missing a call to `process.wait()` —  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55052055/why-do-i-get-subprocess-resource-warnings-despite-the-process-being-dead

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not too clear, but If I assume that you are about to launch a process wich goes to zombie and you want to be able to control that in some state of your script. If this in the case, I propose you the following:

```
p = subprocess.Popen([cmd_list], shell=False)
```

This in not really recommanded to pass through the shell.
I would suggest you ti use shell=False, this way you risk less an overflow.

```
# Get the process id & try to terminate it gracefuly
pid = p.pid
p.terminate()

# Check if the process has really terminated & force kill if not.
try:
    os.kill(pid, 0)
    p.kill()
    print "Forced kill"
except OSError, e:
    print "Terminated gracefully"
```

Comment: - p.pid is a property of Popen instances, not a method

- When exactly is the OSError being raised? Even for simple Popen calls
( subprocess.Popen("ls", shell=False)) I can't seem to get to the except statement.

Comment: it's right, pid is a property, it should be a typing error. For the OSError the exception is raised at the os.kill(pid, 0) step if the pid does not exist anymore - p.terminate() has terminated the pid with success ;-)

Comment: is both `os.kill` and `p.kill` needed? Isnt one enough?

Answer (score 0):

You can use two signals to kill a running subprocess call i.e., signal.SIGTERM and signal.SIGKILL; for example

```
import subprocess
import os
import signal
import time
..
process = subprocess.Popen(..)
..
# killing all processes in the group
os.killpg(process.pid, signal.SIGTERM)
time.sleep(2)
if process.poll() is None:  # Force kill if process is still alive
    time.sleep(3)
    os.killpg(process.pid, signal.SIGKILL)
```

Comment: Instead of `sleep(2)` + `poll` you can use `wait(2)` with a timeout, which won't waste two seconds if the process exits quickly.  Additionally, you can use `process.terminate` and `process.kill` instead of `os.killpg`.

Answer (score 0):

Following command worked for me

```
os.system("pkill -TERM -P %s"%process.pid)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try wrapping your subprocess.Popen call in a try except block.  Depending on why your process is hanging, you may be able to cleanly exit.  Here is a list of exceptions you can check for:  [Python 3 - Exceptions Handling](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_exceptions.htm)