# Python: terminate subprocess without having access to subprocess.Popen object?

Tags: python, terminal, subprocess, terminate

I have a script whereby I simply call a subprocess in Python using the `subprocess` module, like so:

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen(['python3', 'some_Python_script.py']
```

I want to be able to terminate/kill this process. However, after creating my process, in my app I lose access to the `process` object, and thus am not able to commonly terminate it as described in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16866602/kill-a-running-subprocess-call/16866661), using `process.kill`.

However, is there a way to "store" some unique ID of the process, and with it be able to manipulate/terminate it later on (if it is still running)?

For ex., I am thinking of something like

```
process = subprocess.Popen(['python3', 'some_Python_script.py']
process_ID_string = process.id
...
...
*later on*
subprocess.kill(process_id = process_ID_string)
```

Is something like this possible with the `subprocess` module?

Comment: If you can store the PID, why can't you store a reference to the object the same way?

Comment: (and to be clear, it's `process.pid`, as documented at https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.pid)

Comment: Because I am working with `Dash`, and the callbacks within `Dash` behave like local functions in that their variables are also local, except only basic variables like strings can be returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import subprocess, os, signal

process = subprocess.Popen(['python3', 'some_Python_script.py']
processId = process.pid

# later on
os.kill(processId, signal.SIGTERM)
```

Comment: This is perfect. I knew my intuition was on the right track ^^; , but `subprocess`'s doc's weren't making it easy for me to find this functionality. Thank you.