# How to ensure that a task open with subprocess.Popen is killed?

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

I'm creating a `task` with `subprocess.Popen()` in Linux but if the task does not end by itself then `task.kill` does not kill it.

Is there a way of forcing `task` to end?

Right now my code looks like this:

````
task = subprocess.Popen(
        final_list_subprocess, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

try:
    result, errs = task.communicate(timeout=5)
except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
    task.kill()
except:
    task.kill()```
````

Comment: Some answers here might help: [Kill a running subprocess call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16866602/kill-a-running-subprocess-call)

Comment: This helped me: [How to terminate a python subprocess launched with shell=True](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789837/how-to-terminate-a-python-subprocess-launched-with-shell-true)